# dynamically associate a MenuItem with an item in a List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu, menuitem

I'm using C# and I have a list of objects, and I want to show all the objects in a context menu, each object is shown as a `MenuItem`.

When one MenuItem is clicked, I want to refer to the associated object in the `MenuItem_Click()` function.

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>();
ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

foreach(MyObject o in MyList)
{
     MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
     item.Header = o.Name;
     item.Click += MenuItem_Click;
     menu.Items.add(item);
}

menu.IsOpen=true;

void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){

    // Assume the 5th MenuItem is clicked, I need to refer to the 5th object in MyList
    // how to do it?

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick dirty hack that fits the code you currently have: use the `Tag` property.

```
foreach(MyObject o in MyList)
{
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
    item.Header = o.Name;
    item.Tag = o;
    item.Click += MenuItem_Click;
    menu.Items.add(item);
}
```

then you can refer to it this way:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myObj = (MyObject)((MenuItem)sender).Tag;
}
```

Comment: Despite the down vote, this solution does actually answer the OP's question *within the framework he provided*.

Comment: this works perfectly in my case. i'm wondering why it is considered as "dirty" hack...Isn't the Tag property supposed to do things like this?

Comment: @Laz - the tag is there as a general purpose property, AFAIK it has been used for that sort of thing since it was introduced on controls in VB. Personally it isn't my preferred method, I would use data binding using a ListView and have each TemplateItem as a MenuItem, then target a command (passing in the bound MyObject as the CommandParameter). I might post up a sample of this for you later today if I get time.

Answer (score 0):

You could access it by

```
MenuItem nItem = sender as MenuItem;
```

Comment: This gets the MenuItem, the OP wants the data object that was used to populate the MenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickedItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
MyObject myObj = MyList.Find(o => o.Name == clickedItem.Header);
```

Comment: Looking at the code, item.Header == o.Name so MyList.Find(o => o.Name == clickedItem.Header); Answer updated

Comment: @Dave, in my case the name is not a safe identifier in my case, but i think your idea should work in other cases.